# SSRS Column data shown in header

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

Sorry if this has been asked a different way, this was the best way I could think to phrase it.

I'm currently developing a report in SSRS where the customer would like a new page each time the value in one of the columns of the tablix changes. While I've got that down, the customer would also like to have the value that's in the column in question shown in the table header.

I'm running into a mind block on how to do this. I know it's not just as simple as adding the data value into the header.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How did you implement the page breaking when the value in a column changes? What's then shown on the new page?

Comment: Yes, I did do it that way. Each page does show new data based on the column, but if I put just the field in the header it always shows the first value.

Comment: I was actually asking how you implemented the page breaking, not asking if you implemented page breaking because I assumed you had anyway. Will need more details and/or see the XML definition for your report to offer more assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You could add another row inside your detail group on the tablix and format it to look like a header row. Then you could just add your field in that row and have it render for each group change.